# Confusion with interfaces

Tags: go, pointers, struct, types, interface

I'm writing a parser in Go and I have a following code for ast construction:

```golang
type NODE interface {
    GetPosition() (int, int)
}

type EXPRESSION_NODE interface {
    NODE
    expressionNode()
}


// binary node
type BINARY_EXPRESSION struct {
    Operator    string
    Left, Right EXPRESSION_NODE
    Position
}

// implementing the EXPRESSION_NODE interface for BINARY_EXPRESSION
func (s BINARY_EXPRESSION) expressionNode()
func (s BINARY_EXPRESSION) GetPosition() (int, int) { return s.Line, s.Column }
```

So I have an interface EXPRESSION_NODE and BINARY_EXPRESSION struct and the struct implements all the interface methods

And here is my confusion:

```golang
func (self *Parser) ParseBinaryExpression(
    operators []string,
    parser ExpressionParser,
) (*EXPRESSION_NODE, error) {
    self.SetPosition()
    result, err := parser()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, ChainErrs(self.Err(BINARY_EXPRESSION_ERROR), err)
    }
    for Includes(operators, self.stream.Peek().Literal) {
        operator := self.stream.Next().Literal
        right, err := parser()
        if err != nil {
            return nil, ChainErrs(self.Err(BINARY_EXPRESSION_ERROR), err)
            //ERROR: cannot use &(BINARY_EXPRESSION literal) (value of type *BINARY_EXPRESSION) as *EXPRESSION_NODE value in assignment
            result = &BINARY_EXPRESSION{operator, result, right, self.position}
        }
    }
    return result, nil
}
```

So this line

```golang
result = &BINARY_EXPRESSION{operator, result, right, self.position}
```

gives me the following error: `cannot use &(BINARY_EXPRESSION literal) (value of type *BINARY_EXPRESSION) as *EXPRESSION_NODE value in assignment`

So when I do

```golang
var a EXPRESSION_NODE = &BINARY_EXPRESSION{}
```

without pointer everything seems ok, but with pointers...
And the thing is I actually need to return *EXPRESSION_NODE from my function

Comment: Why do you think you need to return a pointer to an interface?

Comment: Because all of my ast nodes contain pointers to their children

Comment: That doesn’t explain what the pointer to an interface is supposed to do. There generally is no reason to store a pointer to an interface, and the pointer within the interface will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[The code in your question is partial, and thus the following is a sketch, not intended as full working code]*

Generally, you almost certainly never want to use a pointer to an interface. What you want instead is a pointer to your type to implement an interface.

First, make sure the pointer to your type implements the interface:

```
type BINARY_EXPRESSION struct {
    Operator    string
    Left, Right EXPRESSION_NODE
    Position
}

// Note that pointer receivers
func (s *BINARY_EXPRESSION) expressionNode()
func (s *BINARY_EXPRESSION) GetPosition() (int, int) { return s.Line, s.Column }
```

And then your parse function would be something like:

```
func (self *Parser) ParseBinaryExpression(
    operators []string,
    parser ExpressionParser,
) (EXPRESSION_NODE, error) {
    // ... stuff ...
    result = &BINARY_EXPRESSION{operator, result, right, self.position}
    return result, nil
}
```

I recommend you learn more about Go interfaces and how to define methods that implement them:

- https://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers
- https://tour.golang.org/methods/4
- https://golangbyexample.com/pointer-vs-value-receiver-method-golang/